# Error while iterating through tf.Data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I want to build a custom ImageGenerator by using yield function in Python. **train_df** is the dataframe which have two columns (**input**: that contains path to my low resolution image and **output** columns contains path to high resolution image. A sample of **train_df** dataframe is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlgV1.png). I made an yield function as Image Generator to pass the images into batchwise manner. Code for ImageGenerator:

```
from numpy import asarray

def get_train_image(dataframe=train_df):

    for i in range(len(dataframe)):
        input_image = cv2.imread(dataframe.input[i],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        input_image=cv2.resize(input_image,(80,120))
        input_image=asarray(input_image)
        input_image=input_image[np.newaxis,...]
        
        output_image = cv2.imread(dataframe.output[i],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        output_image=cv2.resize(output_image,(120,160))
        output_image=asarray(output_image)
        output_image=output_image[np.newaxis,...]
        
        yield tf.convert_to_tensor(input_image),tf.convert_to_tensor(output_image)
```

Image of above code [Image_of_above_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TyW9.png). When I test this by using next function.It works fine [Extracting_data_from_generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6K0G.png). I used DataAdapter provided by tensorflow (tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()) to pass the image in the CNN in batchwise manner and I got error while iterating. Same error is coming when I pass the Data Adaptor to CNN.

`train_data=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator( get_train_image,output_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,120,80,3),dtype=tf.float32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,160,120,3),dtype=tf.float32) ), args=[train_df])`

Image of code above:

[image: Data Adapter Code and the error]

More description of the error:

[image: Error Description]

Comment: please review [ask]. replace those pictures of text with the text they contain. -- next, please review [mre]. you are expected to debug your code a little at least. you are clearly calling that function on something other than a dataframe... which the error message tells you.

Comment: I checked the type of dataframe. It is pd.DataFrame type. It is working fine when I extract information busing next().  It is showing error when I use it as a generator.